# Targeting first and last child when pseudo classes are not allowed

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm creating a custom MUI styled component and I want to add additional styles for the first and last child element. Because MUI uses emotion styled library, I'm not allowed to use `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo classes, because emotion may add `<style>` elements inline, which would fail targeting first and last element children.

emotion also logs an error in the console

```
The pseudo class ":first-child" is potentially unsafe when doing server-side rendering. Try changing it to ":first-of-type".
```

The problem is that I'm not able to change to `:first-of-type` or `:last-of-type`, because my child elements are not the same.

## Question

How do I go about solving this.

#What I also tried
In my component that gets the children I've tried iterating over those and add className props to them to indicate the first and last child (simplified code ahead).

```
// excerpt ComponentWithChildrenIteration
Children
  .toArray(children)
  .map((c, i) =>
    // ...missing code... clone only runs for first and last index and if ReactElement
    cloneElement(c, { className: `${c.className} ${i === 0 ? 'first-child' : 'last-child'}`
  )
```

**But there is a problem.** If the child component just renders elements/components and doesn't even take children (not a container), then I'm unable to access those. I only see the child component and children if it has any. This means recursion wouldn't do the trick. I actually need to see the resulting HTML.

```
<ComponentWithChildrenIteration>
  <Items />
</ComponentWithChildrenIteration>

// where Items
Items = () => (
  <>
    <Text>...</Text>
    <Block>...</Block>
    <SomethingThird>...</SomethingThird>
  </>
);
```

Even if I would traverse the whole children subtree, removing Fragments along the way, I can't know what actually returns some element or not.

Comment: Wouldn't a recursive function help with the nested children?

Comment: @0stone0 not really, because a component may render components within a fragment, but may not have any children. Suppose one of the child components has `<><b>a</b><i>b</i></>`. There is no way to actually check the component's render result. And such a component would provide two elements in the resulting HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually pretty simple. Instead of traversing child components we need to enumerate the resulting HTML elements that get rendered. And this is the code that does just that. It adds a `first-child` CSS class to the first child element and `last-child` to the last one.

The following code is a simplified example that doesn't do any checking whether classes are already present on the elements (would duplicate them) and also doesn't exclude any non-visible elements (non visible as per markup not CSS) like `script` or `style` elements and doesn't take into account textual/comment nodes. But it's a starting point that clearly illustrates the solution.

```
function ComponentWithChildrenIteration({ children }) {
  const elementHtmlRef = createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (elementHtmlRef.current) {
      const childElements = Array.from(elementHtmlRef.current.children);
      if (childElements.length) {
        childElements.at(0).classList.add('first-child');
        childElements.at(-1).classList.add('last-child');
      }
    }
  }, [elementHtmlRef]);

  return (
    <ContainerRoot ref={elementHtmlRef}>
      {children}
    </ContainerRoot>
  );
}
```